# Ionic 4 Slider autoplay

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, slider, ionic4, autoplay

I want to slide automatically the ionic slider but its not working.
slider contains images also.
data is got from API call.

```
  <ion-slides  autoplay="5000" loop="true" speed="300" pager="true" >
        <ion-slide *`ngFor`="let item of topStories">
            <ion-card (click)=" this.newsService.onGoToTopStoryPage(item)">
                <ion-card-content >
                    <ion-img [src] = "item.image"></ion-img>
                    <h2> <b>{{item.title}} </b></h2>
                    <h4>{{item.summary}}</h4>
            </ion-card-content>
            </ion-card>
        </ion-slide>
       </ion-slides>
```

Answer (score 29):

Try this might work in your app:

```
settings the options autoplay to true

slideOptsOne = {
 initialSlide: 0,
 slidesPerView: 1,
 autoplay:true
};
```

page.html

```
<ion-slides [options]="slideOptsOne">
 <ion-slide *`ngFor`="let item of topStories">
   <ion-card (click)=" this.newsService.onGoToTopStoryPage(item)">
     <ion-card-content>
       <ion-img [src]="item.image"></ion-img>
       <h2> <b>{{item.title}} </b></h2>
       <h4>{{item.summary}}</h4>
     </ion-card-content>
   </ion-card>
 </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Add your config in options in the page.ts file. Let me know it's work or not.

Comment: autoplay:true is missing in the document of ionicframework.

Answer (score 9):

Don't use `ion-img`. It shows a broken image for the next slides for the first time. Use `<img>` as shown below.

***Note:*** Ionic team has developed `ion-img` for `ion-virtual-scroll`.

.ts

```
 import { IonSlides } from '@ionic/angular';

  slideOptions = {
    initialSlide: 1,
    speed: 400,
  };

  constructor() { }

  slidesDidLoad(slides: IonSlides): void {
    slides.startAutoplay();
  }
```

.html

```
<ion-slides [options]="slideOptions" pager="true" #slider (ionSlidesDidLoad)="slidesDidLoad(slider)">
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let img of data?.images">
          <img [src]="img">
        </ion-slide>
      </ion-slides>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the typescript file:

```js
export class HomePage {
    slider: any;
    slideOptions = {
    initialSlide: 0,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    autoplay: true
  };
  
  constructor() {}
  slideChanged()
  {
     this.slider.stopAutoplay(); //this code for slide after page change
     }
  }
```

This is the HTML file:

```html
<ion-slides  #slider loop="true" pager="true" [options]="slideOpts" (ionSlideTouchEnd)="slideChanged()" >
  <ion-slide>
    <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/thumb_back/fh260/back_pic/00/02/44/5056179b42b174f.jpg" />
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <img src="https://www.neowebtec.com/images/banner-imgg.jpg" />
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/0b/a3/d6/0ba3d60362c7e6d256cfc1f37156bad9.jpg" />
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you ran into a racing condition. Perhaps the  element was rendered before the data (topStories) is ready. In that case, there is no slide to "autoplay".

Try to put an *ngIf to the  element to render the element when data is ready. For example:

```
this.data_loaded = false;
...

this.apiGetData().then((data) => {
    ...
    this.data_loaded = true;
});


######################################

<ion-slides *ngIf="data_loaded">
...
</ion-slides>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-slides pager #Slider class="slides (ionSlidesDidLoad)="afterslidesLoad(Slider)">
   <ion-slide>
     <img src="image1" />
   </ion-slide>
   <ion-slide>
     <img src="image2" />
   </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>

afterslidesLoad(slides) {
  slides.startAutoplay();
}
```

Above code is my working code. You have to implement startAutoPlay method.

Answer (score 0):

Use input property `[autoplay]="3000"` to pass milliseconds:

```
<ion-slides [pager]="true"  [autoplay]="3000">
    <ion-slide>
      Slide 1
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
      Slide 2
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
      Slide 3
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this solution:

```
  <ion-slides *ngIf="topStories.length!=0" autoplay="5000" loop="true" speed="300" pager="true" >
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let item of topStories">
        <ion-card (click)=" this.newsService.onGoToTopStoryPage(item)">
            <ion-card-content >
                <ion-img [src] = "item.image"></ion-img>
                <h2> <b>{{item.title}} </b></h2>
                <h4>{{item.summary}}</h4>
        </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
    </ion-slide>
   </ion-slides>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to use the autoplay setting in Ionic 5

```
<ion-slides [options]="{ slidesPerView:2, autoplay: {delay: 1500} }">
```